# How to correctly transfer audio from the server to the client?

Tags: javascript, node.js, audio, html5-audio, arraybuffer

I have node.js script. It works with `watson-developer-cloud` to realize text-to-speech feature:

```
var text = event.request.params.text;
var voice = event.request.params.voice;
var TextToSpeechV1 = require("watson-developer-cloud/text-to-speech/v1");

var text_to_speech = new TextToSpeechV1({
    "username": "my-username",
    "password": "my-password"
});

var params = {
  text: text,
  voice: voice
  accept: 'audio/wav'
};

text_to_speech
  .synthesize(params, function(err, audio) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      return;
    }
    console.log("audio ready");
    text_to_speech.repairWavHeader(audio);
    // this string makes answer to client
    event.setResponse(audio, 200, 'audio/wav') 
});
```

I get the answer from the server in fetch and make "Blob" file from it:

```
//code from my promise with "res" function to complete
fetch(`http://my_url_to_generate/text=${text}&voice=${voice}`, options)
    .then(
    function (response) {
        }
        // here I take the arrayBuffet in the response
        response.arrayBuffer().then(function (data) {
            const blob = new Blob([data], { type: 'audio/wav' });
            debugger;
            res(blob)
        })
    }
    )
```

When I stop on debug I see that `blob` was succesfully created, but it have only two properties. I don't know if this is good (I haven't experience of work with files), maybe already at this stage I did something wrong.
[image]

Then I create File - object from my Blob:

```
...
const file = new File([blob], this.state.fileName);
const objectURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
this.props.showPlayer(file, objectURL);
...
```

[image]

ShowPlayer is a function that turn on my player. Player thake objectURL as src. But I have the error here:

[image]

I don't ask you to help me with my error, maybe you can see some error in my audio-file flow  and processing.

Comment: Is there a reason that instead of using fetch() to obtain the audio, the url could be set directly on an audio element as src?

Comment: the sound is not on my server.  User input text, I generate voice, and already after I get it async from the server.